# Angular 2 @ViewChild not working. Cannot Read Property "title" of Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I am unable to access the property of component even after importing with @ViewChild. Below is the code.

**header.monitor.component.ts**

```
import { AdminComponent } from 'admin/admin.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'monitor-header',
    templateUrl: './header.monitor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.monitor.component.css']
})

export class HeaderMonitorComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(AdminComponent) private admin: AdminComponent;

    private monitorTitle: string;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.monitorTitle = this.admin.title;
    }
 }
```

**header.monitor.component.html**

```
<div class="text-center header h3">{{monitorTitle}}</div>
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'monitor-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent {

  constructor() { }

  title = 'Header';

}
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Help me resolve this error.

Comment: template doesn't contain AdminComponent

Comment: The error message is clear. You are referencing @ViewChild(AdminComponent) without having a reference in your header.monitor.component.html. You don't have <monitor-admin></monitor-admin> and  you don't have appropriate template variable (#admin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be checking for the `@ViewChild` in the `AfterViewChecked` instead of the `AfterViewInit`. Also you can bundle your `@angular/core` imports like so: 
`import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';`. Then instead of implementing `AfterViewInit` just implement `AfterViewChecked`.

Here is how it could look:

```
import { AdminComponent } from 'admin/admin.component';
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'monitor-header',
    templateUrl: './header.monitor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.monitor.component.css']
})

export class HeaderMonitorComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

    @ViewChild(AdminComponent) private admin: AdminComponent;

    private monitorTitle: string;

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.monitorTitle = this.admin.title;
    }
 }
```

One question: Are these both parent components or will one of the components be a child of the other? The reason i ask is that you may want to look into a different method of passing that variable between components as this may be achieved with an `@Input` or using a service to store and set the header variable. I hope this can be of some help.

EDIT:

To answer your comment, you should create a service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {

  _title: string;

  constructor() { }

  set title(title) {
    this._title = title;
  }
  get title() {
    return this._title;
  }

}
```

Then in your component import the service and `get` or `set` the variable:

```
import { AdminComponent } from 'admin/admin.component';
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from 'path/to/your/service';

@Component({
    selector: 'monitor-header',
    templateUrl: './header.monitor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.monitor.component.css']
})

export class HeaderMonitorComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

    @ViewChild(AdminComponent) private admin: AdminComponent;

    private monitorTitle: string;

    constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {} // Import service here


    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.monitorTitle = this.headerService.title;
    }
 }
```

You just need to make sure you set the title in one of the components using `this.headerService.title = 'yourTitle';`

I am just not sure which component gets loaded first.

You should check out Angular Services here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Also check out Angular Component Interaction here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

EDIT #2:

Here is another way to subscribe to that title in your Service:

So here below I have created a `Subject` that is of type string, and a method that tells it here is the next string to hold and send.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {

  public titleSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() { }

  setNextTitle(title) {
    this.titleSubject.next();
  }

}
```

Then in your `HeaderMonitorComponent` you would want to subscribe to that `Subject` like so:

```
import { AdminComponent } from 'admin/admin.component';
import { Component, OnInit ViewChild, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HeaderService } from 'path/to/your/service';

@Component({
    selector: 'monitor-header',
    templateUrl: './header.monitor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.monitor.component.css']
})

export class HeaderMonitorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

    @ViewChild(AdminComponent) private admin: AdminComponent;

    private monitorTitle: string;
    titleObservable: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {} // Import service here

    ngOnInit() {

       this.titleObservable = this.headerService.titleSubject.asObservable();
       this.titleObservable.subscribe((title) => {
          this.monitorTitle = title;
       });
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.monitorTitle = this.headerService.title;
    }
 }
```

Then in your `AdminComponent`, whenever the button is clicked, call `this.headerService.setNextTitle(title)` and the new title which you are subscribing to in the HeaderMonitorComponent will then be acknowledged and replace the current value of `monitorTitle`.

Just another quick way to handle the data passing through.

Comment: I also believe you want to explicitly set your title variable to 'public'

Comment: Yup I explicitly set the variable to public. Yea these both are parent components, I will use @Input property instead of ViewChild. But I do not want to use the view of the admin component, Just the properties of admin component. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I edited my answer above to explain how this can be achieved, but take note you should definitely do some more research on how components interact with data between them.

Comment: I want to set the title value in admin component after button click event in admin.component.html and get that value in header component using @Input.

Comment: I added another way to change that title on the fly using the `rxjs/Subject` and `rxjs/Observable`

Comment: Using the final approach I was able to send data only when I injected admin view in the header.component.html. But, when I send data from the separate route of admin view, The header.component is not effected. How to send data with `rxjs/subject` that can effect data in other components on different routes.

Note: I specified in @NgModule Providers and as dependency in both components.