# How to make reference of the element in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, viewchild

I want to see the Element Ref of the ion-card but unable to see that.Below is my code.

**.html**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-card *ngFor="let card of cards" #card>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**.ts**

```
//all imports are made
//class defined

@ViewChild("card", {read: ElementRef}) card: ElementRef;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log('card' -->, this.card); // in the console it displays undefined
    }
```

Comment: tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560394/4826457 ?

Comment: You should tried `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild`.

Answer (score 1):

**.html**

```
<ion-content>
<section #card>
<ion-card *ngFor="let card of cards">
</ion-card>
</section>
</ion-content>
```

Solves the problem!

Answer (score -1):

import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {

constructor(public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {

}

presentActionSheet() {

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({

  title: 'Modify your album',

  buttons: [

    {

      text: 'Destructive',

      role: 'destructive',

      handler: () => {

        console.log('Destructive clicked');

      }

    },{

      text: 'Archive',

      handler: () => {

        console.log('Archive clicked');

      }

    },{

      text: 'Cancel',

      role: 'cancel',

      handler: () => {

        console.log('Cancel clicked');

      }

    }

  ]

});

actionSheet.present();
```

}

}